# Why does the useEffect hook not see my object?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Person = () => {
    const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setPeople(
            { name: "Geoff", age: 51 },
            { name: "Inity", age: 15 },
            { name: "Iniko", age: 6 }
        );
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                {" "}
                HI! My name is {people[0].name} and I'm {people[0].age} years
                old!
            </p>
            <p>
                {" "}
                HI! My name is {people[1].name} and I'm {people[1].age} years
                old!
            </p>
            <p>
                {" "}
                HI! My name is {people[2].name} and I'm {people[2].age} years
                old!
            </p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Person;
```

SO I KEEP GETTING THE ERROR

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: You are passing 3 objects to setPeople method. Pass an object or array there not 3 params and istead of hard coding people write map function and iterate trough it

Answer (score 2):

It's because:

1. You need to wrap the items in square brackets and

```
setPeople([
   ...
])
```

2. when the component first renders the `people` array is empty and you are trying to get a property from an item that is not in the array yet.

Just replace `people[x].name` and `people[x].age` with `people[x]?.name` and `people[x]?.age` (note the `?`) and it will work, but it won't look nice at first render as the text will be displayed without variables (for a fraction of a second). Once you call `setPeople`, the component will render again with the new array of `people`.

However, I wouldn't do this, I would just use a map to display the items:

```
{people.map(p => {
    const { name, age } = p;
    return (<>HI! My name is {name} and I'm {age} years old!</>);
})}
```

This way there will be no error on the first render and the text will display correctly.

Comment: So when I add the '?' it works, but when I do your map it gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you're updating the state. Save it as an array:

```
        setPeople(
           [{ name: "Geoff", age: 51 },
            { name: "Inity", age: 15 },
            { name: "Iniko", age: 6 }]
         )
```

The error is showing because the state is not updated properly.

It is supposed to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the objects inside array when doing `setPeople` in `useEffect` and also add a condition `people &&` to check array is not empty before accessing it. Find below working code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Person = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setPeople(
        [{ name: "Geoff", age: 51 },
        { name: "Inity", age: 15 },
        { name: "Iniko", age: 6 }]
    );
});

return (
    <div>
        <p>
            {" "}
            HI! My name is {people && people[0].name} and I'm {people && people[0].age} years
            old!
        </p>
        <p>
            {" "}
            HI! My name is {people && people[1].name} and I'm {people && people[1].age} years
            old!
        </p>
        <p>
            {" "}
            HI! My name is {people && people[2].name} and I'm {people && people[2].age} years
            old!
        </p>
    </div>
);

};

export default Person;
```